# ReactJS: Redirect to homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom, and I have a problem to redirect to the homepage (path="/").

Basically, I have a form with a submit button. When it is clicked I would to do the redirect.

```
const saveEntity = (event, errors, values) => {
    console.log('values .', values);
    if (values.realm) {
      setRealm(values.realm);
    }
    if (values.ente) {
      setEnte(values.ente);
    }
    if (values.realm) {
      console.log('dentro ', values.realm);
      // const history = useHistory();
      // const handler = () => {
      //   history.push('/');
      // };
      // return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/' }} />;
    }
  };

return (
    <div>
      <AvForm  onSubmit={saveEntity}>
// .....
```

in the saveEntity  I have tried to use history.push or Redirect, but nothing happens when I click the button.

How can I fix?

Thank you

Comment: What is `handler` for? It looks to be the most correct part you have. Returning JSX (the `Redirect` from an `onSubmit` handler will have no effect. JSX must be *rendered*; you aren't rendering the `Redirect`. `history.push` is the correct way to go here, you just aren't calling the `handler` funciton.

Comment: Oh you are rigth, so I should return the handler?

Comment: Probably not. You should probably remove the `handler` function altogether and just call `history.push` directly inside of the `saveEntity` function. **Important note**: I also noticed you called `useHistory` inside of the `saveEntity` function. This breaks the rules of hooks. You must move this hook to the root of the function component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `handler`, just `history.push('/')`. and you have to call `useHistory()` in the root of `YourComponent` as bellow

```
const YourComponnt = ()=>{
const history = useHistory();

const saveEntity = (event, errors, values) => {
    console.log('values .', values);
    if (values.realm) {
      setRealm(values.realm);
    }
    if (values.ente) {
      setEnte(values.ente);
    }
    if (values.realm) {
      console.log('dentro ', values.realm);
    }

   history.push('/'); // or history.replace('/');
  };

return (
    <div>
      <AvForm  onSubmit={saveEntity}>
// .....
}
```

Comment: Ok it works with another route, but If i insert only the history.push('/') it doesn't return to the home

Comment: for example if I write history.push('/application'), the page is redirect. But history.push('/') doens't do nothing

Comment: can you show as how you configured your router, please ? maybe you don't have any component for `/`

Comment: Oh you are right, this was the problem, thank you!